# After SQL server was re-started, SQL Server Agent is not invoking a job at scheduled time

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server Agent job that runs every night at 21:00 and it was working well for years. The job executes stored procedures step by step to create tables first by dropping existing tables and then creating new ones. A few weeks ago our SQL Server was re-started and the agent stopped invoking the job at the scheduled time. There are no error logs, and no success or fail report. It is not invoking the job. So far I have done the following to fix it:

1. Checked the local services of the SQL server for SQL Server Agent to Running and Automatic.
2. Checked SQL server configuration manager for SQL server services, SQL Server Agent to Running and Automatic.

when I run the job manually by right hand clicking the job, start the job at step. It runs well and does the right job which proves that there is no problem with the stored procedure scripts. I can not understand why it is not invoking the job at 21:00 automatically.
What's confusing is that when I am in the office from 8:00 AM in the morning and when I set up the job to run for example at 10:00 am as a test the job gets invoked at 10:00. But when I left office at 16:00 to run the job at 21:00 it doesn't invoke it. Could it be something related to the SQL server in sleep mode etc which might have happened after it was re-started?

Regards

Solomon

Comment: Does the Job Activity Monitor show the next runtime as you expect? Is the schedule enabled? Did you check both the agent log and the sql log? Are there any errors at that time in the event log?

Comment: Also, if the Windows Service Control Manager was used change service accounts, go into the SQL Server configuration managers and change it to Local System and then back to the correct account.  This should give it the correct user rights.  Domain policy can take those away.  Running repair will also put back rights.

Comment: Activity Monitor shows the expected next runtime correctly. On the Activity Monitor it also shows Last Run Outcome as Succeeded. There is no error log. The source SQL server Agent Account Name shows NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Do I need to change this? There are Local account, Local account and member of administrators group, LOCAL SERVICE options available in the box to select.

Comment: The NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT account is the default and is fine.  The Windows Event Viewer will have many events.  Check the system, application, and security event logs around the time the job was scheduled to run and did not run.  Also, double check the steps to insure the correct step is set to start.  Check that each step is set to fail the job upon failure.  Verify that the job is owned by sa.

Comment: Thanks Randy, On SQL Server Configuration Manager, SQL Native Client, Client Protocol I Enabled the Named Pipes and re-started the server. This solved the problem. It is now four days and the agent is invoking the jobs at the scheduled time i.e every night at 22:00. Many thanks for your advice and help.  I am hugely grateful for your follow-up replies